# Multi-level objects - destructive merge based off keys

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, javascript-objects

I have two objects. Basically a model and data situation. Can't figure out how to recursively delete items in the data object, that have been removed from the model.

First is the model:

```
var foo = {
  "title": "Enter title",
  "info": {
    "released": "Enter year",
    "runtime": "Enter time"
  }
}
```

The other one is the data:

```
var bar = {
  "title": "Forrest Gump",
  "info": {
    "released": "1994",
    "runtime": "02:22",
    "awards": "3"
  }
  "genre": "Drama/Comedy-drama"
}
```

I'm trying to do a generic comparison between two objects that would result in:

```
var bar = {
  "title": "Forrest Gump",
  "info": {
    "released": "1994",
    "runtime": "02:22"
  }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

A super bonus would be if it would be able to add object keys+values that exist in the blueprint but not in the data. I have that working separately, but it would be a nice bonus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive function over `Object.keys` should work perfectly:

```js
var foo = {
  "title": "Enter title",
  "info": {
    "released": "Enter year",
    "runtime": "Enter time"
  }
};

var bar = {
  "title": "Forrest Gump",
  "info": {
    "released": "1994",
    "runtime": "02:22",
    "awards": "3"
  },
  "genre": "Drama/Comedy-drama"
}

function getBoth(base, data) {
  var result = {};
  Object.keys(base).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof base[key] == "object" && data[key]) {
      result[key] = getBoth(base[key], data[key]);
    } else if (data[key]) {
      result[key] = data[key];
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getBoth(foo, bar));
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your help Jack. That works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```js
var foo = {
  "title": "Enter title",
  "info": {
    "released": "Enter year",
    "runtime": "Enter time"
  },
  "NOT_EXISTING_IN_DATA": "Test"
}

var bar = {
  "title": "Forrest Gump",
  "info": {
    "released": "1994",
    "runtime": "02:22",
    "awards": "3"
  },
  "genre": "Drama/Comedy-drama"
}



function isObj (a) {
  return a != null && a.constructor === Object;
}

function projectIntoSpec (spec, data) {
  return Object.keys(spec).reduce(function (acc, key) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (!isObj(data[key])) {
        // copy non-object values from data
        acc[key] = data[key];
        return acc;
      }
      // recursively copy object values
      acc[key] = projectIntoSpec(spec[key], data[key]);
    } else {
      // add things which are in the blueprint but not in the data
      acc[key] = spec[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}



console.log(projectIntoSpec(foo, bar));
```

It creates a copy of your data according to everything which is defined in "foo". If it encounters a key in "foo" which doesn't exist in data, it copies the value from "foo".

Comment: Hi David! That works great as well! I only had to do a slight modification to isObj to account for "a" being null. If there was a way to do two green ticks ;). I'm not sure if I'll need to run the update and delete in separate processes. Really appreciate your help, since it solves the problem with the extra step! Thanks a million

Comment: @Andrew: Updated the answer. It now includes the check for `a` being `null` or `undefined` :)